# API for time and distance between two addresses?

Tags: distance, time

The Google TOS appears to limit the use of API for time and distance between two addresses to use in conjunction with a displayed map. Does anyone know of any other mapping data source that offers a similar API without that limitation? I need JUST time and distance, for use in driver scheduling and management, not directions and such.

Answer (score 1):

The [OSRM](http://www.project-osrm.org) project has an [API](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/API%20Usage%20Policy), but they have restrictions. You may want to consider building your own instance.